# Follow me, and your urologist will be buying himself a new yacht

Tags: meaning-in-context, jokes

The following<sup>1</sup> is a retort from the dean of a hospital to her highly insubordinate lead-diagnostician.

> In a little place called "follow me, and your urologist will be buying himself a new yacht."

The above diagnostician wants to know where the dean is planning to meet someone, and is known to use a private investigator to snoop on people without their consent.

---

The problem is, I have no idea what the above is supposed to mean. I know what a urologist is (but not who she would be referring to). I know what a yacht is (really expensive boat). I know the dean would want to do something to penalize the diagnostician in case he followed the dean. However, it sounds like the punishment for insubordination is something completely random.

**What is it supposed to mean?**

<sup>[1]</sup><sub>Source: *House M.D., Season 5 Episode 6*</sub>

Comment: I wonder if the quote should be "In a little place called 'follow me', and your urologist will be buying himself a new yacht.", meaning that if you just do what he says, he will get rich.

Comment: It kind of sounds like he's warning that you will be so freaked out by what you see that you pee yourself.

Comment: @MarkRogers Do you go to see a urologist to clean up after you pee yourself? ;)

Comment: @GreenAsJade - If it was uncontrollable and frequent!

Comment: @user3169 - the full quote is: `House: Where are you meeting her? 
Cuddy: A little place called 'Follow Me And Your Urologist Will Be Buying Himself A New Yacht'.`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I don't know the series, and it is possible there is something in the story that it is referring to. But my guess is that it means "If you follow me, you are going to need some expensive surgery to the part of your body that urologists treat".

Comment: Oooooh, that *does* make sense.

Comment: This is *exactly* the intended meaning.

Answer (score 28):

I haven't seen the series in a while, so I'm a bit fuzzy on the exact scene details, but basically:

> "Follow me, and your urologist will be buying himself a new yacht."

Dr. Lisa Cuddy is warning House, that if he follows or stalks her, that she will hit or break his balls/groin so bad that he will have to see his urologist so much, such that the urologist will be able to afford a new yacht.

So basically,  like Colin Fine said, it means

> "if you follow me, I'll break your balls."

Or something to that effect. The indirect and clever way some of the House retort/dialogue is worded is one of the awesome things that I loved about the series.

Comment: Thanks. This explains a bit more explicitly what the joke was.

Comment: This answer is nice; as an English learner I did not understand Colin's answer until I read this one. In particular, the "follow" meaning as in "stalking" and the act of hurting/retaliation didn't come through (to me at least).

Comment: Glad to help. My native language isn't English, so I understand the need to explain as clearly as possible! :)